# Get the last value based on prior value stored in another column using sql

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

current have this data in my database

as you can see in the screenshot i've seperate the highlighted value into group lets say blue is group one and group 2 is red

here's the thing row 1,3,4,5,6,7 is connected because of the source1 and ben_prior column where where ben_prior stores the old value and the souce1 stores the new value it is subsequent change until it reaches row 7 my main goal is to get the latest value based on those the groups

row 2 is a stand alone data since it didn't match any ben_prior value on the screenshot.

that said the expected result of the question should get the row 2 and row 7 any idea how to translate this in a query?

[image]

this is my data

```
INSERT INTO #temptable ([id], [payment_start_date], [payment_stop_date], [trustee_export_date], [txn_date], [transaction_type], [source1], [ben_prior])
VALUES
( 188585, N'2014-10-01T00:00:00', NULL, N'2014-10-01T00:00:00', N'2014-09-02T00:00:00', 'Start', 243.40, 0.00 ), 
( 188588, N'2014-10-01T00:00:00', NULL, N'2014-10-01T00:00:00', N'2014-09-01T00:00:00', 'Start', 246.16, 0.00 ), 
( 307777, N'2014-10-01T00:00:00', NULL, N'2018-02-01T00:00:00', N'2017-12-21T00:00:00', 'Change', 989.37, 243.40 ), 
( 307782, N'2014-10-01T00:00:00', NULL, N'2018-03-01T00:00:00', N'2017-12-21T00:00:00', 'Change', 258.38, 989.37 ), 
( 393309, N'2014-10-01T00:00:00', NULL, N'2020-03-01T00:00:00', N'2020-01-22T00:00:00', 'Change', 258.38, 258.38 ), 
( 407605, N'2014-10-01T00:00:00', NULL, N'2020-04-01T00:00:00', N'2020-03-12T00:00:00', 'Change', 1447.99, 258.38 ), 
( 418956, N'2014-10-01T00:00:00', NULL, N'2020-05-01T00:00:00', N'2020-04-13T00:00:00', 'Change', 272.28, 1447.99 )

DROP TABLE #temptable
```

Comment: I'm too old to read that tiny image text.

Comment: What if yellow row will have the same `ben_prior` value? Looks like it is some decimal measure, but in general you build relationships on some identifying columns, not measures.

Comment: Also please post your data as text and describe the calculation logic without *yellow* and *red*, but some formal criteria

Comment: SO generally discourages images to represent data or tables. You have not specified your database provider, but in general, you will want to look a the `LAG()` windowing function. That said, while the concept that `ben_prior` matches `source1` from a previous column makes sense, it does not make sense to have that as the _sole_ criteria for relating two or more transactions. There ought to be some key to match on as well. Imagine your row #2 `source1` happened to also be `243.40`...

Comment: lets just say this only happens in transaction_type = Change.

i've posted the data i've got edited the question.

Comment: You need to build update hierarchy and find the "final" value, right? Anyway, there should be some glue apart from amount, because you at least can have the same amount at some previous day

Comment: you can refer to trustee_export_date column which indicates the latest data for the group based on source1 value and ben_prior in my example row 7 has the latest trustee_export_date